# How can I use Algolia on Shopify to show accurate search results when I input more than one word in the search box?

Tags: shopify, algolia, shopify-app

I am using algolia app for my shopify project. When I tried to input two words in the search box, the `autocomplete` results are really accurate. The problem is that when I hit enter key to go to `instant search` page, the results are not accurate anymore. Is there any settings to help me fix this problem?

This is the screenshot on my problem:

[image: Autocomplete]

[image: Instant search]

Answer (score 1):

If you already [enabled Instant Search on your shop](https://www.algolia.com/doc/integration/shopify/building-search-ui/instant-search/) and still have the default Shopify search results page, it's most likely the provided CSS Selector is incorrect.

The Instant Search widget provided by our Plugin needs a CSS Selector in order to render the results in the search results page.

If you wonder how to find the proper CSS Selector value, please read [this post](https://discourse.algolia.com/t/enable-instant-search-finding-the-css-selector-solved/2311) that explains how to do it.